# React, Material UI, Select, disableScrollLock, make menu position relative to anchor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const names = [
  "Oliver Hansen",
  "Van Henry",
  "April Tucker",
  "Ralph Hubbard",
  "Omar Alexander",
  "Carlos Abbott",
  "Miriam Wagner",
  "Bradley Wilkerson",
  "Virginia Andrews",
  "Kelly Snyder"
];

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  },
  disableScrollLock: true
};

export default function App() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ height: "1000px" }}>
      <FormControl>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-mutiple-name-label"
          id="demo-mutiple-name"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The codes can be found here as well https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-leaf-ooko1

I am using React 16, latest Material UI core, Material UI Select Component

What I am trying to do here is when I open the drop down menu (with disableScrollLock=true), when I scroll the window, the drop down menu will be relative to the anchor element not fixed on window. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not acquainted with React but I've managed to find a working example with a different component.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011607/152016

Coder used a `ReportComboBox` instead of a `Select`, but he tackled another problem of your snippet: growing selection size.

When in your snippet you select a lot of items, there is a UI problem.

Enough digressing, I've changed the answers' snippet to enable scrolling (by setting `body { height: 3000px; }` for instance, and you can see that the scrolling keeps the select box in its place: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-ellipsis-one-row-example-k62hy

Hope this is enough for solving the problem or at least a clue to it.

Comment: Thanks, I need the windows to be able to scroll, and the drop down menu is not fixed on screen but on the parent element. I am looking for solution with Material UI select, and see if that is possible

Comment: Well, the last codesandbox's select isn't fixed on screen, when you scroll it goes away from viewport as a static select would. And also you've a problem in your original sandbox, with many user selections, which is solved in the answer I've talked about.