# How to handle overflow condition in react-select component by replacing selected option with " ... " ellipsis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have react-select component in multi select mode . When selected elements no longer fit the width of container , the component starts to grow in height

[image: Overflowing react-select component]

Is their any way to style react-select component such that instead of growing vertically selected options are cropped and replaced with " ... " while keeping the selected options highlighted in the options dropdown

Example -

[image: Example of overflowing react-select with ellipsis]

[image: Example of react-select component with highlighted selected options in dropdown]

Comment: You might refer to this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157792/react-select-multi-select-and-text-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157792/react-select-multi-select-and-text-overflow) Hope you get your answer

Comment: You might refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157792/react-select-multi-select-and-text-overflow Hope you get your answer

Comment: @hastikukadiya I did , but the code seems not be working properly . Instead of selected options being highlighted in dropdown they dont appear at all